# how is this login form demo making the "please fill in field" popup?

Tags: php, html

I've been using a template I found for a login form at:     http://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/hflzK

```
        <body>
    <div class="container">
        <section id="content">
            <form action="">
                <h1>Login Form</h1>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="username" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
                    <a href

="#">Lost your password?</a>
                <a href="#">Register</a>
            </div>
        </form><!-- form -->
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#">Download source file</a>
        </div><!-- button -->
    </section><!-- content -->
</div><!-- container -->
</body>
```

It has a nifty popup next to any field left empty when submitting that says "Please fill out this field". I'd like to add this functionality to other custom forms I'm using but after looking through the html and css code, I can't find out how their triggering that popup.

Can anyone spot it?

Comment: It uses HTML5 and the `required` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As long as you're using HTML5 and the `required` property on your inputs this message will popup when you attempt to submit the form.

At the top of each HTML5 page you declare the `doctype`:

```
<!doctype html>
```

OR

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The for each required input use the `required` property:

```
<input name="userpass" placeholder="passphrase" type="password" value="" required />
```

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out right after submitting the question but i'll give you the point xD